# how to associate one aspect method with multiple methods in aspectj?

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I have a class `A`:

```
@Service
public class A {
    public void goX()    {
        System.out.println("goX");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void goY()    {
        System.out.println("goY");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and an AOP class `AOP`:

```
@Aspect
@Service
class AOP        {
    @Around("execution(* com.test.A.goX(..))")
    public void calExecTime(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable        {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t2-t1);
    }
}
```

Then I can count the time `A.goX()` takes to execute by method `AOP.calExecTime()`.

**What I want is to calculate the time for both `A.goX()` and `A.goY()` by the same method `AOP.calExecTime()`**, I don't know how to write things in `@Around` annotation. Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could help.

```
@Aspect
@Service
class AOP        {
@Around("within(* com.test.*)")
public void calExecTime(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Method "+ proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " time : "+  t2-t1);

    }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! What if `goX` and `goY` are in different class? If there any way to write **AND** in `@Around`?

Comment: Yes, you can use within(you package.*) instead of execution. No matter how many classes you have in this package your method calExecTime will called for all classes. But plz make sure this should not create any memory issues. I have updated the same in the answer. Also please very here for more about AOP. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html